# java - File charset

Tags: java, windows, file, character-encoding

I have an application, which proccesses some text and then saves it to file.

When I run it from NetBeans IDE, both `System.out` and `PrintWriter` work correct and non-ACSII characters are displayed/saved correctly. But, if I run the JAR from Windows 7 command line (which uses the `cp1250` *(central european)* encoding in this case) screen output and saved file are broken.

I tried to put `UTF-8` to `PrintWriter`'s constructor, but it didn't help… And it can't affect `System.out`, which will be corrupted even after this.

**Why is it working in the IDE and not in `cmd.exe`?**
I would understand that `System.out` has some problems, but why is also output file affected?

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: In my locale I change font in cmd.exe properties. After that console output with non-ASCII symbols looks well. May be this helps you

Comment: problem with console persists, but file problem was some kind different - data have been downloaded from web and during processing from byte to String, I forgot to "consider" charset...

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem.
Actual reason of that is because when your code is ran in NetBeans environment, NetBeans automatically sets properties of the system.

You can see that when you run your code with NetBeans, the code below probably prints "UTF-8". But when you run it with cmd, you sure will see "cp1256".

```
System.getProperty("file.encoding");
```

You should notice that while using 'setProperty' will change the output of 'getProperty' function, it will not have any effect on Input/Outputs. (because they are all set before the main function is called.)

Having this background in mind, when you want to read from files and write to them, It's better to use codes below:

```
    File f = new File(sourcePath);
```

For reading:

```
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(
    new FileInputStream(f), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
```

and for writing (I have not tested this):

```
OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(
    new FileOutputStream(f), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
```

the main difference is that these Classes get required Charset in their constructors, but classes like FileWrite and PrintWrite don't.
I hope that works for you.